# How to simplify exponents of the form $\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{N}(N+1)\right)$ inside a function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm really annoyed with Mathematica and I need your help.
I defined a discrete Fourier-Transformation(I use II instead of N, because Mathematica wont let me-.-):

```
Subscript[ϕ, i_] = Sum[Exp[I (2 Pi)/II i k] f[k], {k, II}];
```

And I want to check that

```
Subscript[ϕ, 1] == Subscript[ϕ, II + 1]
```

This gives me 
$$\sum _k^{\text{II}} \left(f(k) e^{\frac{2 i \pi  k}{\text{II}}}\right)=\sum _k^{\text{II}} \left(f(k)
   e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (\text{II}+1) k}{\text{II}}}\right)$$

And by simply splitting the exponents on the right side of the equations this can be seen to be true.($\exp(i2\pi k)=1\forall k\in\mathbb N$ )
I really would have thought that Mathematica would be able to simplify that on its own, considering that $k$ is the summation index and is therefore an integer, but it does not.
So I told Mathematica:

```
Simplify[Subscript[ϕ, 1] == Subscript[ϕ, II + 1],     Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]
```

Didn't help, so I tried:

```
Simplify[Subscript[ϕ, 1] == Subscript[ϕ, II + 1] /. 
        Exp[a_] :> Exp[Expand[a]], Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]
```

Still does not work! Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, simplifying a `Sum` does not result in simplifying each term in the `Sum`.  Try

```
Subscript[ϕ, 1] == Subscript[ϕ, II + 1] /. 
    Exp[a_] :> Simplify[Exp[a], Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]
(* True *)
```

Undoubtedly, there are more elegant approaches.

Answer (score 4):

`Simplify` does not simplify held arguments of a function (that's a `\[CapitalNu]`, not an `N`, just for fun):

```
ClearAll[foo];
SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll];
Simplify[foo[E^((2 I k π (1 + Ν))/Ν) ], {k, Ν} ∈ Integers]
Simplify[E^((2 I k π (1 + Ν))/Ν), {k, Ν} ∈ Integers]
(*
  foo[E^((2 I k π (1 + Ν))/Ν)]
  E^((2 I k π)/Ν)
*)
```

This should seem perfectly reasonable, since the arguments are held for a reason.  If they were to be evaluated inside the operations of `Simplify`, the returned expression might not be equivalent.  This is indeed irritating with a function like `Sum`, which has the attribute `HoldAll`.  If you're certain that the summand can be evaluated outside the `Sum`, then something like the following should work:

```
Assuming[{k, Ν} ∈ Integers,
 FullSimplify[
  Subscript[ϕ, 1] == Subscript[ϕ, Ν + 1], 
  TransformationFunctions ->
    {Automatic,
     # /. Sum[t_, i__] :> With[{t0 = Simplify[t]}, Sum[t0, i]] &}]
 ]
(*  True  *)
```

For extra security, you could wrap it in `Block[{k},...]`.